# Telerik AsyncUpload trying to rename file get IOException

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asynchronous, telerik

i want to rename my file. But i got a IOException. It says "The Process Cannot Access the File Because It Is Being Used by Another Process".

This is my Code:

asp.net:

```
<telerik:RadAsyncUpload ID="rauKachelUpload" runat="server" ChunkSize="0" Localization-Cancel="Löschen" Localization-Remove="Entfernen" Localization-Select="Auswählen"
  Culture="de-DE" Skin="MetroTouch" MaxFileInputsCount="1" OnFileUploaded="rauKachelUpload_FileUploaded">
</telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
```

vb.net:

```
Protected Sub rauKachelUpload_FileUploaded(sender As Object, e As FileUploadedEventArgs)

    Try
        Using fileStream As Stream = e.File.InputStream
            Using img As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fileStream)
                Dim h As Integer = img.Height
                Dim w As Integer = img.Width
                img.Dispose()
                Dim fileName As String = e.File.GetName()
                If w = MaxWidth And h = MaxHeight Then
                    rauKachelUpload.TargetFolder = "img/kachel_grafik"

                    Dim TimeStamp As String = DateDiff("s", "01/1/1970 12:00:00 AM", DateTime.Now)
                    fileName = "KI_" & TimeStamp & WelcheSparteUndGröße

                    KachelPfad = "~/img/kachel_grafik/" & fileName
                Else
                    KachelFalsch = True
                End If
                If KachelFalsch = False Then

                    e.File.SaveAs(fileName)

                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock([GetType](), "CloseScript", "redirectParentPage('VermittlerBearbeiten.aspx?ID=" & VermittlerID & "&KBFN=" & KachelPfad & "&NA=true" & "&fwg=" & WelcheSparteUndGröße & "&Ang1=" & hfAng1CHK.Value & "&Ang2=" & hfAng2CHK.Value & "&Ang3=" & hfAng3CHK.Value & "&Ang4=" & hfAng4CHK.Value & "&AngSrc1=" & hfKachelIMGSrcBaufi.Value & "&AngSrc2=" & hfKachelIMGSrcImmo.Value & "&AngSrc3=" & hfKachelIMGSrcPhoto.Value & "&AngSrc4=" & hfKachelIMGSrcAsse.Value & "');", True)
                Else
                    rnfIconNichtErzeugt.Visible = True
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        rnfIconNichtErzeugt.Visible = True
    End Try

End Sub
```

Without trying to rename my file, it works fine.

Does anyone has an Idea what i did wrong?

Thanks for reading.
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the fileStream is properly closed before attempting to rename the file since the particular file will be held by the fileStream object. You can try fileStream.Close() after the img.Dispose() statement.